# how to draw an arc with line using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw shape shown in figure. Background is white.. Hope it is visible to you..

[image]

I am using bezier path to draw this. I have provided bounds to shape as shown by blue border.

[image]

So far I am successfully able to draw just two lines(shown in green). I have to draw the one with red further.

[image]

I am unable to draw arc from this point. I can't understand how to pass correct parameters to `addArcWithCenter`.

**Code**

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //declare and instantiate the UIBezierPath object
    aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))];

    // Draw some lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 40)];
    [aPath addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:40 startAngle:3 *(M_PI / 2) endAngle:M_PI clockwise:NO];

    //set the line width
    aPath.lineWidth = 2;

    //set the stoke color
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];

    //draw the path
    [aPath stroke];

}
```

I am new to core graphics. Please be lenient over me.. Thanks..

Comment: What is your rect size ( i hop > 80 * 80 as you define radius=40) Your arc should look like a 3/4 circle or just 1/4 ?

Comment: Of how much size should my view rect be so I can draw arc at the position shown in figure?

Comment: Based on your image, should you not be using `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:` ?

Comment: @Wain I really don't have any idea that which function would be best to use at this point. Please can you guide me? Thanks.

Comment: CAN you add picture With what should be the next step (2 green lines + arc as it should be in red).

Comment: Plz see my edit. I have added pic.

Comment: I have previously written [a blog post about Bézier path construction](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/) which shows both arcs and curves with both UIBezierPath and CGPath. I hope that it helps you learn how to use the API.

Comment: thanks for the link @DavidRönnqvist. I will surely go through it soon :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this (as you can see, I've used addQuadCurveToPoint a variant of addCurveToPoint proposed by @wain - ask google for addCurveToPoint and switch to picture search to see how it work )  :

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath * aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))];

    // Draw some lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))];



//changes start here !

    //the point look to be at 80% down
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) * .8)];


    //1st arc
    //The end point look to be at 1/4 at left, bottom
    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect) / 4, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    CGPoint cp = CGPointMake( (CGRectGetMaxX(rect) / 4) + ((CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - (CGRectGetMaxX(rect) / 4)) / 2) , CGRectGetMaxY(rect) * .8);

    [aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:p controlPoint:cp];


    //2nd arc
    //The end point look to be at 80% downt at left,
    CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect) * .8);
    CGPoint cp2 = CGPointMake( (CGRectGetMaxX(rect) / 4) / 2 , CGRectGetMaxY(rect) * .8);

    [aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:cp2];


    //close the path
    [aPath closePath];

    //set the line width
    aPath.lineWidth = 2;

    //set the stoke color
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];

    //draw the path
    [aPath stroke];
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It seems like a magic to me :D You are awesome man. You made many things clear for me.

Comment: One thing I want to ask from the code: How did u calculate points for control point? Can you clarify it a little?

Comment: Imagine your "arc" in a rect, I choose to put the control point in the middle X, top Y of this rect. Your really need to check the doc to see how it work : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) - check for **Adding Curves to Your Path**